# Email not formatting for gmail

Tags: email, gmail, mailchimp, yahoo

[How it shows in Gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdxub.png) 
[How it shows in Yahoo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjoZr.png)
[Accurate Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hlOH.png)

I've been having a problem with an email not formatting correctly for some platforms. It seems to remove images and background colors in yahoo, and just messes everything up in Gmail. Apple it is perfectly fine.

I'm not super knowledgable in code, I can just make changes but not sure what exactly to add or change to be compatible with all platforms. I think it has to do with the way background colors and pictures are coded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary -->
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine -->
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
    <!-- Disable auto-scale in iOS 10 Mail entirely -->
    <title></title>
    <!-- The title tag shows in email notifications, like Android 4.4. -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:200,300,400,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- CSS Reset : BEGIN -->
    <!-- CSS Reset : END -->
    <!-- Progressive Enhancements : BEGIN -->

  <style type="text/css">
        html,body{
            margin:0 auto !important;
            padding:0 !important;
            height:100% !important;
            width:100% !important;
            background:#f1f1f1;
        }
        *{
            -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
        }
        div[style*=margin: 16px 0]{
            margin:0 !important;
        }
        table,td{
            mso-table-lspace:0 !important;
            mso-table-rspace:0 !important;
        }
        table{
            border-spacing:0 !important;
            border-collapse:collapse !important;
            table-layout:fixed !important;
            margin:0 auto !important;
        }
        img{
            -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
        }
        a{
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        [x-apple-data-detectors],.unstyle-auto-detected-links *,.aBn{
            border-bottom:0 !important;
            cursor:default !important;
            color:inherit !important;
            text-decoration:none !important;
            font-size:inherit !important;
            font-family:inherit !important;
            font-weight:inherit !important;
            line-height:inherit !important;
        }
        .a6S{
            display:none !important;
            opacity:.01 !important;
        }
        .im{
            color:inherit !important;
        }
        img.g-img+div{
            display:none !important;
        }
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 374px){
        u ~ div .email-container{
            min-width:320px !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 413px){
        u ~ div .email-container{
            min-width:375px !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px){
        u ~ div .email-container{
            min-width:414px !important;
        }

}       html,body{
            margin:0 auto !important;
            padding:0 !important;
            height:100% !important;
            width:100% !important;
            background:#f1f1f1;
        }
        *{
            -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
        }
        div[style*=margin: 16px 0]{
            margin:0 !important;
        }
        table,td{
            mso-table-lspace:0 !important;
            mso-table-rspace:0 !important;
        }
        table{
            border-spacing:0 !important;
            border-collapse:collapse !important;
            table-layout:fixed !important;
            margin:0 auto !important;
        }
        img{
            -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
        }
        a{
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        [x-apple-data-detectors],.unstyle-auto-detected-links *,.aBn{
            border-bottom:0 !important;
            cursor:default !important;
            color:inherit !important;
            text-decoration:none !important;
            font-size:inherit !important;
            font-family:inherit !important;
            font-weight:inherit !important;
            line-height:inherit !important;
        }
        .a6S{
            display:none !important;
            opacity:.01 !important;
        }
        .im{
            color:inherit !important;
        }
        img.g-img+div{
            display:none !important;
        }
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 374px){
        u ~ div .email-container{
            min-width:320px !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 413px){
        u ~ div .email-container{
            min-width:375px !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px){
        u ~ div .email-container{
            min-width:414px !important;
        }

}       .primary{
            background:#f5564e;
        }
        .bg_white{
            background:#ffffff;
        }
        .bg_light{
            background:#fafafa;
        }
        .bg_black{
            background:#000000;
        }
        .bg_dark{
            background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        }
        .email-section{
            padding:2.5em;
        }
        .btn{
            padding:12px 20px;
            display:inline-block;
            text-transform:uppercase;
            letter-spacing:2px;
            font-weight:600;
        }
        .btn.btn-primary{
            border-radius:30px;
            background:#36b1ce;
            font-size:13px;
            color:#ffffff;
        }
        .btn.btn-white{
            border-radius:5px;
            background:#ffffff;
            color:#000000;
        }
        .btn.btn-white-outline{
            border-radius:5px;
            background:transparent;
            border:1px solid #fff;
            color:#fff;
        }
        h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
            font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif;
            color:#000000;
            margin-top:0;
        }
        body{
            font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif;
            font-weight:400;
            font-size:15px;
            line-height:1.8;
            color:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        }
        a{
            color:#f5564e;
        }
        .logo h1{
            margin:0;
        }
        .logo h1 a{
            color:#000;
            font-size:20px;
            font-weight:700;
            text-transform:uppercase;
            font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif;
        }
        .navigation{
            padding:0;
        }
        .navigation li{
            list-style:none;
            display:inline-block;
            margin-left:5px;
            font-size:12px;
            font-weight:700;
            text-transform:uppercase;
        }
        .navigation li a{
            color:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
        }
        .hero{
            position:relative;
            z-index:0;
        }
        .hero .overlay{
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            right:0;
            bottom:0;
            content:'';
            width:100%;
            background:#000000;
            z-index:-1;
            opacity:.3;
        }
        .hero .icon a{
            display:block;
            width:60px;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
        .hero .text{
            color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
            padding:0 4em;
        }
        .hero .text h2{
            color:#ffffff;
            font-size:40px;
            margin-bottom:0;
            line-height:1.2;
            font-weight:300;
        }
        .heading-section h2{
            color:#000000;
            font-size:30px;
            margin-top:0;
            line-height:1.4;
            font-weight:300;
        }
        .heading-section .subheading{
            margin-bottom:20px !important;
            display:inline-block;
            font-size:13px;
            text-transform:uppercase;
            letter-spacing:2px;
            color:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
            position:relative;
        }
        .heading-section .subheading::after{
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            right:0;
            bottom:-10px;
            content:'';
            width:100%;
            height:2px;
            background:#f5564e;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
        .heading-section-white{
            color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
        }
        .heading-section-white h2{
            line-height:1;
            font-weight:300;
            font-size:30px;
            padding-bottom:0;
        }
        .heading-section-white h2{
            color:#ffffff;
        }
        .heading-section-white .subheading{
            margin-bottom:0;
            display:inline-block;
            font-size:30px;
            text-transform:uppercase;
            letter-spacing:2px;
            font-weight:300;
            color:rgba(255,255,255,.4);
        }
        .icon{
            text-align:center;
        }
        .services{
            background:rgba(0,0,0,.03);
        }
        .text-services{
            padding:20px 10px 0;
            text-align:center;
            background:#fafafa;
        }
        .text-services h4{
            font-size:15px;
            text-transform:uppercase;
            letter-spacing:.5px;
            color:#36b1ce;
            font-weight:600;
        }
        .services-list{
            padding:0;
            margin:0 0 10px;
            width:100%;
            float:left;
        }
        .services-list .text{
            width:100%;
            float:right;
        }
        .services-list h3{
            margin-top:0;
            margin-bottom:0;
            font-size:15px;
        }
        .services-list p{
            margin:0;
        }
        .text-tour{
            padding-top:10px;
        }
        .text-tour h3{
            margin-bottom:0;
        }
        .text-tour h3 a{
            color:#000;
        }
        .text-services .meta{
            text-transform:uppercase;
            font-size:14px;
        }
        .text-testimony .name{
            margin:0;
        }
        .text-testimony .position{
            color:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        }
        .counter{
            width:100%;
            position:relative;
            z-index:0;
        }
        .counter .overlay{
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            right:0;
            bottom:0;
            content:'';
            width:100%;
            background:#000000;
            z-index:-1;
            opacity:.3;
        }
        .counter-text{
            text-align:center;
        }
        .counter-text .num{
            display:block;
            color:#ffffff;
            font-size:34px;
            font-weight:700;
        }
        .counter-text .name{
            display:block;
            color:rgba(255,255,255,.9);
            font-size:13px;
        }
        ul.social{
            padding:0;
        }
        ul.social li{
            display:inline-block;
        }
        .footer{
            color:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
        }
        .footer .heading{
            color:#ffffff;
            font-size:20px;
        }
        .hidden{
            display:none;
        }
        .footer ul{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        .footer ul li{
            list-style:none;
            margin-bottom:10px;
        }
        .footer ul li a{
            color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
        }
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px){
        .icon{
            text-align:left;
        }

}   @media screen and (max-width: 500px){
        .text-services{
            padding-left:0;
            padding-right:20px;
            text-align:left;
        }

}</style></head>
  <body width="100%" style="margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; background-color: #222222;">
    <center style="width:100%;background-color:#f1f1f1;">
      <div style="display:none;font-size:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;font-family:sans-serif;">
        ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ 
      </div>
      <div style="max-width:600px;margin:0 auto;" class="email-container">
        <!-- BEGIN BODY -->
        <table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="margin:auto;">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="bg_white" style="padding:1em 2.5em;">
              <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <td width="40%" class="logo" style="text-align:left;">
                    <h1>
                      <a href="https://moveandstore.com"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0d9e3bf61406dcc2f6b321e6d/images/beabaa6f-844f-4ffa-9080-6391df1c3ef6.png" style="max-width:200px" alt="beabaa6f-844f-4ffa-9080-6391df1c3ef6.png"></a>
                    </h1>
                  </td>
                  <td width="60%" class="logo" style="text-align:right;">
                    <ul class="navigation">
                      <li>
                        <a href="tel:2056244537"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0d9e3bf61406dcc2f6b321e6d/images/ee34875d-ab9f-480d-a11e-150f8027462c.png" style="max-width:25px" alt="ee34875d-ab9f-480d-a11e-150f8027462c.png"></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <!-- end tr -->
          <tr>
            <td valign="middle" class="hero bg_white" style="background-image:url('https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0d9e3bf61406dcc2f6b321e6d/images/1698dfdb-e067-4d6d-acb8-436d9e86c3d4.jpg');background-size:cover;height:400px;">

              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="text" style="text-align:center;">
                      <h2></h2>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <!-- end tr -->
          <tr>
            <td class="bg_dark email-section" style="text-align:center;">
              <div class="heading-section heading-section-white">
                <h2>We have a new website!</h2>
                <p>We're so excited to unveil our new website! Our website is now easy to navigate to our services, get a quote, and schedule your move. We're excited to give our customers a new, top notch experience to make their move as easy as possible.</p>
                <p><a href="https://moveandstore.com" class="btn btn-primary">visit the site</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- end: tr -->
        <tr>
          <td class="bg_white">
            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td class="bg_white">
                  <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="bg_white email-section">
                        <div class="heading-section" style="text-align:center;padding:0 30px;">
                          <h2>All New Service Pages</h2>
                          <p>We've redesigned and reinvented how deliver our services. We have a general breakdown of each service, plus a detailed service page for those of you who want to learn more specific details.</p>
                        </div>
                        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                          <tr>
                            <td valign="top" width="50%">
                              <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                  <td style="padding-top:20px;padding-right:10px;">
                                    <a href="https://moveandstore.com/services/residential"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0d9e3bf61406dcc2f6b321e6d/images/6a5e0310-9a5a-4b52-8487-4702c8cf4fb3.png" alt="" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100px; height: auto; margin: auto; display: block;"></a>
                                    <div class="text-tour" style="text-align:center;">
                                      <h3>
                                        <a href="https://moveandstore.com/services/residential">Residential</a>
                                      </h3>
                                      <span class="price">Services include Local Moving, Long Distance and Labor.</span>
                                    </div>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td style="padding-top:20px;padding-right:10px;">
                                    <a href="https://moveandstore.com/services/collegiate"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0d9e3bf61406dcc2f6b321e6d/images/e5542099-d033-42ae-8f32-c9198cdc6e00.png" alt="" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100px; height: auto; margin: auto; display: block;"></a>
                                    <div class="text-tour" style="text-align:center;">
                                      <h3>
                                        <a href="https://moveandstore.com/services/collegiate">Collegiate</a>
                                      </h3>
                                      <span class="price">Services include Dorm Store, Lease Layover, Local Moving, and Labor.</span>
                                    </div>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td style="padding-top:20px;padding-right:10px;">
                                    <a href="https://moveandstore.com/services/commercial"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0d9e3bf61406dcc2f6b321e6d/images/22fec672-03f3-4285-a75c-9dc4e1ef78f3.png" alt="" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100px; height: auto; margin: auto; display: block;"></a>
                                    <div class="text-tour" style="text-align:center;">
                                      <h3>
                                        <a href="https://moveandstore.com/services/commercial">Commercial</a>
                                      </h3>
                                      <span class="price">Services include FF&amp;E, Employee Relocation, Corporate Relocation, and Instutional Moving.</span>
                                    </div>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </td>


                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- end: tr -->
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <!-- end:tr -->
              <tr>
                <td class="bg_white email-section" style="width:100%;">
                  <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="middle" width="50%">
                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0d9e3bf61406dcc2f6b321e6d/images/6f23aa84-082e-4dba-9d2f-ca5c9fd414af.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto; margin: auto; display: block;">
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td valign="middle" width="50%">
                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                          <tr>
                            <td class="text-services" style="text-align:left;padding-left:25px;">
                              <div class="heading-section">
                                <h3>Moving Tips</h3>
                              </div>
                              <div class="services-list">
                                <div class="text">
                                  <h4>1. Pack up your things</h4>
                                  <p>A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies</p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="services-list">
                                <div class="text">
                                  <h4>2. Search for Destination</h4>
                                  <p>A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies</p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="services-list">
                                <div class="text">
                                  <h4>3. Be Responsible</h4>
                                  <p>A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies</p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <!-- end: tr -->
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Leave a Review -->
        <tr>
          <td class="bg_light email-section">
            <div class="heading-section" style="text-align:center;padding:0 30px;">
              <h2>Leave us a Review!</h2>
              <p>Had a good moving experience in the past? Please leave us a review on Google!</p>
              <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Leave a Review</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : END -->
    </table>
    <table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="margin:auto;">
      <tr>
        <td valign="middle" class="bg_black footer email-section">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top" width="60%" style="padding-top:20px;">
                <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left;padding-right:10px;">
                      <h3 class="heading">Follow Us</h3>
                      <p>Get the latest updates!</p>
                      <ul class="social">
                        <li><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0d9e3bf61406dcc2f6b321e6d/images/31d75ed2-3027-49aa-b9f2-1969b2cb1f4b.png" alt="" style="width: 30px; padding-right:10px; max-width: 600px; height: auto; display: block;">
                        </li>
                        <li><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0d9e3bf61406dcc2f6b321e6d/images/1f92f2b1-2e26-4add-acf8-b4f8c2056309.png" alt="" style="width: 30px; padding-right: 10px; max-width: 600px; height: auto; display: block;">
                        </li>
                        <li><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0d9e3bf61406dcc2f6b321e6d/images/63ede42c-5969-4eb5-8f64-5aa9add11cf6.png" alt="" style="width: 30px; max-width: 600px; height: auto; display: block;">
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td valign="top" width="40%" style="padding-top:20px;">
                <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;">
                      <h3 class="heading">Contact Info</h3>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <span class="text">130 Industrial Drive<br>Birmingham,AL 35211</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <span class="text"><a href="tel:2056244537">205-624-4537</a></span>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- end: tr -->
      <tr>
        <td valign="middle" class="bg_black footer email-section">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top" width="50%">
                <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left;padding-right:10px;">
                      <p>© 2019 Move &amp; Store. All Rights Reserved.</p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td valign="top" width="33%">
                <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:right;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;">
                      <p><a href="*|UNSUBSCRIBE|*" style="color:rgba(255,255,255,.4);">Unsubscribe</a>
                    </p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your hero image is a background image, but if you make it into a regular image, the hero will display in every major email client, including Gmail and Yahoo.

Try this instead:

```
<tr>
  <td valign="middle" class="hero bg_white" style="">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0d9e3bf61406dcc2f6b321e6d/images/1698dfdb-e067-4d6d-acb8-436d9e86c3d4.jpg" width="600" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

I pulled out the empty `h2` below the image to make it simpler to display the relevant code.

Before I did this, your email hero did not display in Outlook 2007-2019. Even with changing the hero to an `img`, you have serious issues with this email in Outlook and other clients. I suggest more testing and development to help make sure your customers see your message.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes there was originally an overlay on it and a headline over the picture that's why it was a background image. I think I've actually figured out emails don't like CSS and need to put all the style in the code itself